# How to remove a SKSpriteNode correctly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm doing a small game in `Swift 3` and `SpriteKit`. I want to do a collision with my character and a special object that increases my score in 1, but for some reason, when I detect the collision, the score increases in 2 or 3.

I'm removing from parent my `SpriteKitNode` but it seems that it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
func checkCollisionsObject(){

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "objeto") {node, _ in
        let objeto = node as! SKSpriteNode
        if objeto.frame.intersects(self.personaje.frame){
            objeto.removeFromParent()
            self.actualizarPoints()
            //self.labelNivel.text = "Level: \(self.nivel)"
        }
    }

}


func actualizarPoints() {

    self.pointsCounter += 1
    points.text = "Points: \(pointsCounter)"

}
```

Comment: Why you don't use collision delegate?

Comment: How I should use collision delegate? @SimonePistecchia

Comment: May be you must read some tutorial like this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145318/spritekit-swift-3-tutorial-beginners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the collision detection is happening at 60fps (pretty fast). So in that time multiple collision detections are occurring. You are just handling the first one.

I usually like to have a property on the object that I can trigger so that I know whether or not the object has collided, and set it so that it doesn't detect anymore collisions.

In your case the object is just a SKSpriteNode so you would have to set the property in userData or make the object a custom object and have the property in the custom object class

```
func checkCollisionsObject(){

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "objeto") {node, _ in
        let objeto = node as! CustomObject
        if objeto.frame.intersects(self.personaje.frame) && objeto.hasCollided == false {
            objeto.hasCollided = true
            objeto.removeFromParent()
            self.actualizarPoints()
        }
    }
}

func actualizarPoints() {

    self.pointsCounter += 1
    points.text = "Points: \(pointsCounter)"

}
```

Comment: happy to help out